# Cannot connect to neo4jclient in WPF designmode

Tags: c#, wpf, neo4jclient

I have an object that populates itself using data pulled from a neo4j database using neo4jclient.

This object is the datacontext for my Window. (I know I should be doing MVVM but this is a simple dev ui that will be replaced with a real one later).

I wanted to get this to work in design-mode so I set the proper attributes on the window:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=actorTester:DesignActor,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

here is the relevant part of the  constructor for the dataconext object:

```
GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

this works fine at runtime, but at design time I get:

```
Method not found: 'System.String Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.get_Path()'
```

when it tries to do the connect. I can find no reference on this method anywhere, it does not seem to be part of Newtonsoft.JSON

I am at a loss as to how to resolve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried updating JSon.net via nuget? (get_Path() is a getter for the `Path` property)

Comment: nuget doesn't offer any updates, and the version I have is pretty new (6/6/13) so I ddon't think that is it. Plus, it works fine at run-time, just not at design-time

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's already a different version of JSON.NET in memory in the designer, loaded by something else.

I'd fire up fuslogvw and take a look at the Fusion logs to see what assemblies are being loaded, from where, and why. You will see a different version of JSON.NET getting loaded here.